# What's the best way to index ~1TB of richtext douments in Solr?

Tags: java, search, solr, apache-tika

I'm trying to index around 1.2 million files (1TB) of doc, pdf, xls, msg and other files. I'm using a Java crawler which goes through each file and posts it to Solr using a process that executes an update/extract cURL command, with periodic commits.

At the moment it takes around 75 hours to index, which is awkwardly long. I've seen other methods online for increasing index speed but given we're indexing richtext documents not just text or CSV I'm not sure which of them would apply to our situation.

The files are up to 25MB and can be thousands of pages of length, so I'm thinking what's slowing it down is Tika extracting all the text. I'm not sure how to get around this, at the end of the day we'll have to use Tika to get the content one way or another.

I saw posts saying multithreading can be used for indexing, however I don't have much experience in it so before I attempt to struggle through creating a way to do that I thought I'd see if anyone has any ideas about another way that might increase indexing time (or something obvious I missed).

Thanks

Comment: Multi threading is surly a good way to go. You can use the Java Executors, without much effort it will be multi threaded indexing process. Another things is, as you are only indexing the documents to the Solr, keep your `autoSoftCommit` to a high value like 15 minutes or 30 minutes. Similar settings for the `autoCommit` as well. Later you can update these configurations and reload the core.

Comment: Alrighty then, I'll have a look into it. Yeah I just checked the solr config and autoCommit was firing off like every 15 seconds -_- so I increased that too.

Thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly you should consider a building index by using Hadoop. This option available from Solr 4.9 (see issue [SOLR-1045](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1045)) and allows to use several machines for index creation.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll check it out. We should have multiple machines to work with once we deploy so this could work well.